# ASPNet Core Conditionally Set Response Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an endpoint that serves up a users Avatar. If one isn't set, it generates an Identicon for their name. If they do have one set, it returns that avatar.

Right now I am using the `[ResponseCache]` Attribute to cache this endpoint. Instead, I only want to cache the endpoint IF they have an avatar set.

The problem is users, don't have an avatar, they go set one, and it doesn't update around the site because its cached in the browser.

Is there a way to move this into the Action and make it conditional?

```
    [HttpGet("~/fetch-avatar")]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = int.MaxValue)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAvatar(long userId, ResizeMode mode = ResizeMode.Pad, int width = 0, int height = 0, string downloadName = "") {
        var user = await userAppService.GetUserById(userId);

        var startChar = user.Slug.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];
        var color = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        if (startChar >= 'a' && startChar < 'e') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        } else if (startChar >= 'e' && startChar < 'j') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        } else if (startChar >= 'j' && startChar < 'n') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        } else if (startChar >= 'n' && startChar < 'r') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
        } else if (startChar >= 'r' && startChar < 'v') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
        } else if (startChar >= 'v' && startChar < 'z') {
            color = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Avatar)) {
            var g = new IdenticonGenerator()
            .WithAlgorithm("SHA256")
            .WithBlockGenerators(IdenticonGenerator.ExtendedBlockGeneratorsConfig)
            .WithBackgroundColor(color);
            var avatar = g.Create(user.Slug);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                avatar.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
            }
        }
        try {
            return await FetchImage(user.Avatar, mode, width, height);
        } catch {
            var g = new IdenticonGenerator()
                           .WithAlgorithm("SHA256")
                           .WithBlockGenerators(IdenticonGenerator.ExtendedBlockGeneratorsConfig)
                           .WithBackgroundColor(color);
            var avatar = g.Create(user.Slug);
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                avatar.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "image/png");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In you code, we can find the action method accept query string `userId`, do you mean client pass a specific userId (who don't have an avatar), but get cached content?

Comment: @FeiHan Yes, client passes a userId and if there is no avatar, it returns the Identicon (and no caching), if there is an avatar it returns that and caches it.